# Удаление лишних пробелов в строке

Tags: python

Функция нормализует имя и выводит его без лишних пробелов

```
def normalize_name(s):
    s=s.title()
    s=re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s)
    return s

name=input()
print(normalize_name(name))
```

Но когда я ввожу :

`sir Arthur     Conan   Doyle`

между словами пробелы убирает, а в начале и в конце всё равно остаются лишние пробелы.

`s=re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s)`

- что тут не так?

Answer (score 3):

Лишние пробелы у вас не "остаются" - вы их сами ставите, заменяя несколько пробелов "\s+" (один и больше) на один пробел (" ").
поэтому я вам советую сначала избавиться от крайних пробелов, а потом применять re.sub:

```
s ="    sir Arthur     Conan   Doyle "
s = s.strip()
s = re.sub(r"\s+"," ", s)
```

`sir Arthur Conan Doyle`

Comment: функция возвращает none

Comment: и вот это лишнее s ="    sir Arthur     Conan   Doyle "

Comment: я не знаю, что у вам там лишнее, и что возвращает None - у меня _мой_ пример великолепно работает.